# Spring Boot, JPA-Hibernate does not translate MySql exceptions to DataAccessException

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

We have the below configurations for our spring boot application. We are using the hibernate and MySql database.

The problem here is that when we face an `java.sql.SQLException` in `public Entity getXXX(Long xxx)`, we are not receiving the translated exception by spring. Hibernate translates the underlying exceptions to `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` hierarchy But we need the spring translation which is the `DataAccessException` hierarchy.

We have this configuration for our JPA-Hibernate:

```
package ....;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

    private final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf.getObject());
        txManager.setJpaDialect(emf.getJpaDialect());
        txManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        txManager.setPersistenceUnitName(activeProfile);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

With this properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap_mode=lazy
spring.datasource.name=${xxx}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=${xxx}
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=600000
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.autocommit=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
```

And when we execute our JPA queries using the below:

```
@Repository
public class XxxxxDaoImpl implements XxxxxDao {

@Override
public Entity getXXX(Long xxx) {
   try {
       return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM xxx c " +
               "INNER JOIN c.xx e ON e.id = :xxx " +
               "INNER JOIN FETCH xxx i", xxx.class)
           .setParameter("xxx", xxx).getSingleResult();
   } catch(DataAccessException e) {
       // It will not enter the catch because the type of exception is of javax.persistence.PersistenceException!
       log.error("DAO: exception in querying xxx for xxx: {} => {}", xxx, e.getMessage());
            return null;
   }
}
}
```

So When there is no entity for this query, it always raise `javax.persistence.NoResultException` which is the sub-class of `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` and not the `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException`.

In the log I can see these lines:

```
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'spring.sql.init-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'spring.jpa-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'spring.jpa.hibernate-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'hikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProvider' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.metadata.DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration$HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration$$Lambda$449/0x00000008403ab840] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.postProcessAfterInitialization:376: Bean 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' of type [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

It says that `Bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors` so might it be the reason for this? Because I know that this exception translation is a kind of post processor.

I have searched for days in jpa, hibernate documentation and tried stackoverflow but no result! We need DataAccessException which is the Spring translation.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I tried to make it more clear. Problem is that we expect to receive translated exception by spring on the form of DataAccessException but in contrary we always receive javax.PersistenceException. It would be great if you can help @Jens

Comment: Why you can’t use the javax exception? Add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: it is needless to say that we want to use the DataAccessException throughout our data layer. DataAccessException works with Spring Repository so for the consistency throughout our code we want to have the same in the hibernate!

Comment: have you tried/caught on a higher (than `@Repository`..i.e. service/controller) layer?

Comment: oh! we did not try that! we were trying to capture the no result exception in the dao so we can sent back Optional empty or null to the caller in the service layer. but let me try that and update here.